# remove chainguard (?) lockring on fixed cup bracket

Tags: bottom-bracket

I'm trying to remove the part of the frame that was holding the chainguard but there seems to be a kind lockring and I don't know which tool to use. Any ideas?

EDIT: I am referring to the topmost six-edge nut, NOT the lockring (I do have a C spanner for that.)

EDIT: I've accepted ojs's answer: the six-notch cup is the *fixed* part of the cup, it's not supposed to be removed at all unless the bottom bracket is completely replaced (and that was *not* my goal); the lockring is supposed to be removed without removing the cup. I took the bike to a mechanic who pointed out that this is a *reverse-threaded* cup, which I knew, however since the cup is reverse-threaded so is the lockring (it cannot be otherwise). The whole lot was seized and rusty (the mechanic had to hammer it a lot). Apparently I made things much worse but tightening it further while trying to unscrew it. Lessons learned.

[image: lockring]

Comment: Generally speaking it makes a better photo if you can clean it up as much as possible before taking the photograph.   I think you have a six-notch cup in the middle, and there's a 4 notch lockring around the outside, - I can make out 3 of the notches.  For something like this I'd bust out the sliding lockjaw pliers and undo the lockring using force, and replace the whole assembly with a cartridge bearing unless you are striving for originality.

Comment: What is this bike? I've never seen a bottom bracket with this pattern. I would say get it out of there by any means necessary as you will likely never reinstall another bottom bracket that requires this tool (unless you choose to)

Comment: @Paul it's a cheap bike (~ £120) I bought 5 years ago, I don't plan to put that cup back, as far as I understand it's to hold the chainguard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool is called lock ring wrench, or in non-bike contexts hook wrench or hook spanner. There are a few different sizes, measure the lock ring before buying one.

EDIT: The inner part is locked by the lock ring. Once the ring is loose, the inner part should be finger tight. If it's stuck, penetrating oil and pipe wrench or the pin spanner from other answer should help.

Comment: I was referring to the topmost 6-edge nut, not the actual lockring.

Comment: It's locked with the lockring and should be loose once lockring is loosened.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use a flathead screwdriver and hammer to tap it out, but it will put nicks into the nut and possibly damage it, but if that isn't much of a factor, cheap and easy. There are a few other tools you can use, either a universal wrench like this:
[image: Universal Spanner]

Or a more specific tool similar to this one:[image: 8-Prong Tool]

This particular one has 8 prongs where yours has 6, so check to make sure the tool you get will match the make and model of your bottom bracket set before you go this route.

You can also take your bike into a bike shop. They will almost always just pop it off for you, if it won't take too long. Maybe charge you $5, but in the shop I worked at, we would have done something this simple for free (and we had all those tools already. Remember, they are trying to compete with online shops now, so their biggest selling point is "in person" customer service)

// EDIT - Actually, it might look more like this (but less prongs):
[image: Internal Tool]

As @Paul pointed out, that other one is for the outer ring, this one, however, is for the internal cone. I didn't see the size difference because there was nothing to compare it too. I actually have the exact 6 prong one you are looking for, somewhere, in some closet, but the bike I bought it for broke a while back and I haven't needed to use it since, ever.

//EDIT2 - Here is an example of what to use in your situation, both the external lock nut as Daniel shows, and the spanner shown above (slightly different spanner.) I'd suggest getting a spanner, since they are more versatile than the other brand specific tools listed.[image]

Comment: The bottom one looks like the one I need, any idea how it's called so I can search for it?

Comment: @thanos that is a park bbt-18 or similar by another brand. This is not likely the tool you need, is it designed to remove truvativ gigapipe bottom brackets (among others possibly) such as this https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81P3U5Z9FoL._SX522_.jpg

Comment: Correct, the tool in the bottom picture is _not_ the tool I need at all since I didn't have to remove the fixed cup anyway. Even if I had to, there is no way that this fragile tool could unscrew it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd tend to use something like this:

[image]

Comment: I was referring to the topmost 6-edge nut, not the actual lockring.

Comment: You loosen the lockring, then use a tool similar to a freewheel tool to remove the cone.

Comment: I purchased and used the above tool and it worked fine for locking back the lockrings. The tool was no good removing the locking at the fixed cup as it was seized, the mechanic had to hammer it.